# Creation apk from html file with android studio

Tags: android, html, android-studio

I'm new from the app creation.
I have searched a lot, but I didn't find anything, maybe I didn't searched the correct words.
I have two questions:
1. I have wrote the code of a *hybrid* app with html, php and jquery. 
So my project is composed of html file and folders (css, font, js, etc...).
Now, I would like to create an apk with android studio. 
How can I proceed? 
How can I obtain the apk from html file with android studio? 
Is it possible?
2. I saw a project for an app that contain the folder platforms, plugins, www and the file config.xml.
What type of project is it? 
How can I obtain this project structure?
Thank you so much

Comment: You should inspect http://phonegap.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are talking about is a **Hybrid App**.

You can create a project with **Cordova** and add your html to it.

https://cordova.apache.org/

There you can find all you need to start with it.

After you create it you can generate a signed apk via Android Studio and publish it.

I hope it helped!